# How to move div lowered from edge of page

Tags: html, css

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jw6kU/2/ of what i have right now. The thing i need to do is drop the white box and the text in that div tag ("left") down so it is center in the green bar at the top (67px tall). How can i easily do this? Sorry this is sloppy, the work was done fast.

This is a second post. The first one i messed up by pasting the wrong link. Sorry.

Comment: You should edit your first post with the correct details rather than starting a duplicate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the margin-top css property would give the div space from the top of the page. You'd have to find the right amount of pixels and test it out fully but I think that will help.

I added this to the css of your fiddle and got the white div at the top in the center of the green div under it.

```
#left {
    margin-top: 9px;
    padding-top: 12px;     
}
```

Comment: This worked great for the white box thanks. Although i seem to be having problems with the text. I put a `<span style="margin-top:9px;">University of Kansas</span>` for the text and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You would need to apply it to the whole div. The best way to do that is avoid the span and use a DOM id. All that means where you would put <div><p>text</p></div>, you could put <div id="divID"><p id="pID">text</p></div>. Now you can use the #divID and #pID tags in your css and apply all the styles you want and get rid of the span. Try adding an id to the div that your text is inside and playing with margin properties.

Comment: I see that is the same div. I got it working in your fiddle and edited my answer. The margin property will shift the div while the padding will pad the inside of the div.